# how to list all child tables under the specific super table in TDengine database?

Tags: tdengine

how to list all child tables under the specific super table in TDengine database? Which SQL command should I use? I use select * from the super table but it only shows all the records, and I also tried to use select distinct(id) from the super table, with a unique id for each child table but it's troublesome, is there any convenient way?

Answer (score 1):

use `select tbname from db.stb` because each child table has a unique table name